# Monitor changes to an array

Tags: javascript

I'm using a third party javascript library in my application and I need to be able to monitor a particular array property for changes. So for example, the third party library adds an object to `widget.loadingQueue` anytime a widget is being loaded. I want to be able to monitor this property and display a loading indicator anytime there are elements in the array. The library is open source, but if possible I'd like to do this without having to go through their source and find every time they add something to the array and add in a method call.

Comment: if you only need to watch that one array, and since this is just a UX enhancement, not a core cog, a setInterval-based observer  can handle it pretty well. If you need more than 10 setIntervals, look into something more structured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they add to the array by calling `push()`, you can simply create a custom `push()` method on the array that runs your handling code and calls `Array.prototype.push()`.

This is how Google Analytics' `_gaq` array works.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great lead for me to go off of. Unfortunately, it appears that the library isn't calling `pop` to remove the elements so I'll have to dig a bit deeper on that one, but `push` is working well.